# "Keep something" vs "stand by something"

Tags: sentence-construction, word-meaning, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

I have heard both of the sentences below in quite similar cases. I wonder if you could let me know how can I distinguish between them and how they differ in meaning? do they mean the same thing?

> 1) Keep your promise. 
>   2) Stand by your promise.

Or I've heard many times they say:

> 3) I'll keep my word. 
>   4) I'll stand by my word.

I wonder if you could let me know more about these structures.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean *exactly* the same thing in this sentence, even though Merriam Webster's descriptions may seem a little confusing...

[keep](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/keep?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld):

> *transitive verb*
>
> **2** : to take notice of by appropriate conduct : FULFILL: such as
>
> **a** : to be faithful to
>
> *// keep a promise*

[stand by](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stand%20by):

> *transitive verb*
>
> : to remain loyal or faithful to : DEFEND
>
> *// stood by his decision*

Comment: Thank you @TypelA. Then can we say that the sentences below mean the same too: "I still **stand by** what I said" = "I still **keep** what I said" Right?

Comment: @A-friend No, "I still **keep** what I said" is wrong. I'm very sorry that I can't explain why - it just is! "I still stand by what I said" is fine and idiomatic.

Comment: After thinking about it a bit, I can't think of any other word that goes with this meaning of "keep." "To keep a promise" seems to be a unique phrase. (There are other meanings of "keep" that go with other words, such as "to keep watch (over)" but that's a different meaning.) On the other hand "to stand by" in this sense can go with anything.